# Why must there be degeneracy in the orbitals to have a Jahn-Teller effect?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, crystal-field-theory

Why is it the case that for Jahn-Teller effects to occur in transition metals there must be degeneracy in either the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ or $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals?

Comment: Jahn-Teller effect is way broader than transition metals, or t2g, or eg.

Comment: What do you mean? But for transition metals there must be degeneracy

Comment: I mean just what I said, Sure, there must be degeneracy in any case. But even when occurring in transition metals, Jahn-Teller effect is not restricted to t2g/eg thing.

Comment: A nice non-inorganic case of JT distortion, let me mention that, is that of cyclobutadiene: in its equilibrium structure (singlet state), it "escapes" antiaromaticity (and degenerancy) with asimmetry. The reason of JT distortion is pretty much the same in inorganic chemistry: an asymmetric (so, non-degenerate) state is energetically favoured compared to the degenerate and symmetric alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the abstract to the [original Jahn-Teller paper](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1937.0142) it is stated:<sup>[1]</sup>

> We shall show that stability and degeneracy are not possible simultaneously unless the molecule is a linear one.

Thus the Jahn-Teller effect is *specifically* about the removal of a degeneracy, and that that will always lower the total energy of the system. Thus you can not have a Jahn-Teller effect without a degeneracy in the reference, fully symmetric state.

---

**Reference:**
[1]: H. A. Jahn, E. Teller, *Proc. Royal Soc. A* **1937**, *161*, 220–235. DOI: [10.1098/rspa.1937.0142](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1937.0142).

Comment: That is correct. But the JT theorem concerns the degeneracy of a *state*, not the degeneracy of two (or more) *orbitals*, which is what OP is asking about. There is almost certainly a direct link, which would be insightful to flesh out (I am unwilling to think about it properly now, although I think it should be easy to show that an uneven population of degenerate *orbitals* leads to a degenerate *state*).

Comment: Good point - I mentally missed the word orbital